# Translation of "Being a person is getting too complicated. Time to be a unicorn."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

My idea of translation:

> Ein Mensch zu sein wird zunehmend zu kompliziert. Es ist an der Zeit, ein Einhorn zu sein.

What is a better translation that has more style and sounds more German?

Answer (score 4):

> Menschsein wird allmählich zu kompliziert. Einhornsein ist angesagt.

You should not combine *zunehmend* and *zu*.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to keep it as simple as the original:

> Mensch zu sein wird zu kompliziert. Es ist Zeit ein Einhorn zu sein.